# Triangle at right of div on hover

Tags: html, css

I'm building this new HTML/CSS design for a website, but I am only allowed to touch the CSS file.

I need a div to get a triangle at the right end on over like this:

[image]

This is the current code:

```
.slider_button_out{
    cursor:pointer;
    height:49px;
    width:174px;
    margin-bottom: 1px;
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.5, #0C4B9D),color-stop(1, #023C7F));
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, #0C4B9D 50%, #023C7F 100%);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, #0C4B9D 50%, #023C7F 100%);
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, #0C4B9D 50%, #023C7F 100%);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(bottom, #0C4B9D 50%, #023C7F 100%);
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #0C4B9D 50%, #023C7F 100%);
}

/*the div down here is the div that displays on hover */
.slider_button_over{
    display:block;
    cursor:pointer;
    background-image: none;
    height:49px;
    width:174px;
    margin-bottom: 1px;
    background-color: #ed1c24;
}
```

Note that I can only touch the CSS, so I can't add a div or something.

Comment: Use this css triangle generator and apply it to the end of your div http://apps.eky.hk/css-triangle-generator/

Comment: @Adsy thanks, but how can I apply it to the end? when I can't add a new div to html?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
.container {
    margin-left: 15px;
    width: 200px;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    border: 1px solid #CAD5E0;
    padding: 4px;
    position: relative;
    min-height: 200px;
}

.container:after {
content: '';
display: block;
position: absolute;
top: 80px;
left: 100%;
width: 0;
height: 0;
border-color: transparent transparent transparent #CAD5E0;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 10px;
}
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2r4Md/)**

Comment: ah I see, thank you. I'll try this if it works ur the best ;P

Comment: with a little bit of editing it worked just fine! thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

If i rigth understand you - you can use pseudo elements such us CSS - The :before Pseudo-element. If you do not understand explanation on w3c for example i try to write code